# YouTube Api for android exception "service_missing"

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to play you tube video in my android application

I got exception while youtube initialization like "service_missing".

I write following code,

```
package com.example.youtubedemo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.*;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements OnInitializedListener{

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "MY API KEY";

    static private final String VIDEO = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6XXgeAkBfQ&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9Wam5jE-9oY8l6RpeAx-XM";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
                findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, MainActivity.this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(this, ""+YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_MISSING,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean arg2) {
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO);

    }

}
```

> I had also given INTERNET users permission.
>
> I test this code in 4.2.2 With google API AVD.
>
> android:minSdkVersion="8"
>
> android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Any one have any idea??

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As [the API documentation for the Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeInitializationResult) states:

> `YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_MISSING`
>   The YouTube API service is missing on this device.

You'll need to install the Youtube app into the emulator to make it work.

Comment: You can use something like [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) as an emulator with Google Play Services installed which allows you to get the Youtube application.

Comment: On Android 11 (30) API I have YouTube app installed but still the same issue, prior 30 API everything works fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631893/youtube-api-oninitializationfailure-service-missing-on-android-11-sdk-30

Comment: @user25 page not found

Comment: there are package visibility restrictions from android 11 and onwards,
add the below code in your manifest file:

<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>

referene: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Answer (score 52):

The issue with Android 11 is the os is restricting access to other apps.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility

Add the following to manifest tag in AndroidManifest to fix YouTube issue:

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Updating this query is not working. YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_INVALID

Comment: You should also check for YouTube App be installed on the device.

Comment: @ZahraJamshidi Any Specific version of the youtube app?

Comment: According to their documentation:
"Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API."

REF: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player